# How to make the watwp.codeplex.com NuGet Phone.Storage.Sample application work?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am interested in working with blob storage from a Windows Phone app.

The Windows Azure Toolkit for Windows Phone should enable this. http://watwp.codeplex.com/

They have a sample application on NuGet which you install in a default WP application from VS, by running the command:

PM> Install-Package Phone.Storage.Sample, in the Package Manager Console

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Phone.Storage.Sample

The only configuration needed to run the app is to change the default navigation page in WMAppManifest.xml to "/Pages/StoragePage.xaml".

But when I try to run this sample application in a default WP app from VS, I get the **error:
"The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format. RequestId:38df4766-0da8-4212-84a1-3da0c994a876 Time:2012-06-06T14:50:02.0209600Z"
Any idea what to do to make it work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you just made one changes in your sample, I believe you are using Azure Storage Emulator. Have you verified if Azure Storage Emulator is running. Also be sure to have a physical network in your main machine rather then virtual network to connect as i have seen such problem with virtual network and loopback address.

It is very much machine specific issue as I just tried to exact same step with no error. There could be any random error for this issue and while you try to restart the machine, re-install sdk and other components and it will go away. I can  help you to find some ways to trouble shoot it:

When you run this application in WP emulator, while using Development storage the HTTP request pass through localhost:PORT/storage_container means the network traffic is on localhost so you can run fiddler to capture traffic on 127.0.0.1 (by default it is not set so you need to configure it. Once you have network trace you can find the root cause however it would hard to find the fix, as i have seen in past.